# Return function when jquery event triggers

Tags: jquery, function, events, wait

How can I force a function to wait for an event to trigger?
I want something like a confirmation box, that user can not do anything until he/she answers the question.

Something like this:

```
function ask() {
    if ($('a').click(function())) {
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

PS: I know how to use "confirm()" in js. I'm writing a new sample of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with two functions:

```
function ask() {
    if ($('a').click(function())) {
         execute();
    }
}

function execute(){

}
```

Comment: I need the main function to return a result!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').click(function() { 
    return confirm('Do you really want to do this?'); 
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that in plain javascript...

```
function yourFunction(){
    return "something";
}


if(confirm('are you sure?')){
    yourFunction();
}
else{
    //do something else...
}
```